# How to get 4 responsive columns to 2 on mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap grid to have 4 responsive columns as shown:

```
[] [] [] []
```

but then on mobile I would like it to look as follows:

```
[] []
[] []
```

but when I use the column I end up getting the following on mobile:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

How to I fix it so that it's 2 x 2? I was initially using the class "col-md-4" but that was unsuccessful so I tried doing two columns within the class

See below: this on mobile does the 1 x 4 format but does 2 x 2 on tablet

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    This is option 1.
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    This is option 2.
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    This is option 3.
</div>    
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    This is option 4.
</div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML and remember "mobile first" approach.  Your task is extremely easy with Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    This is option 1.
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    This is option 2.
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    This is option 3.
</div>    
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    This is option 4.
</div>  

 </div>
```